# Chrome Remote Desktop Service doesn't start

Tags: google-chrome, debian, services, chrome-remote-desktop

So i tried Setting up a headless chrome remote desktop instance on my debian server. I've followed [this](https://bytexd.com/install-chrome-remote-desktop-headless/) Tutorial and got to the part, where i should paste the Command provided by google with my personal token. But the process fails and tells me that i failed to start the service due to a "bad-setting".

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Output of the Startup and of `systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service`

```
chrome-rdp@Scar-Zap:~$ DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
Enter a PIN of at least six digits:
Enter the same PIN again:
[0712/132934.297857:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(559)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
[0712/132934.381309:INFO:host_stopper.cc(38)] Stopping existing host: 8d262ed7-bfd9-4f29-827d-db02959b72fd. This may take a few seconds.
[0712/132934.428811:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(559)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
[0712/132934.561290:ERROR:service_client.cc(132)] Received error code: 5, message: Requested entity was not found.
[0712/132934.672329:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(99)] The daemon is not currently running

[sudo] password for chrome-rdp:
[0712/132938.749337:ERROR:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(101)] Failed to start chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service: Unit chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service' for details.

Couldn't start host.
chrome-rdp@Scar-Zap:~$ systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service
● chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service - Chrome Remote Desktop instance for chrome/rdp
   Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit chrome-remote-desktop@chrome-rdp.service has a bad unit file setting.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```